# React Native, Android Log.

Tags: java, android, react-native

Is there a way in react native to see the log from native (java) modules of android?

I'm using javas log module https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html - but I'm not getting anything from there. and to be honest I'm not sure how to use it if it's at all possible. atm there isn't much code - it's just

```
    Log.d("Notification","Notify App");
```

Because I want to see if I can see the notifications somewhere - I do know the java module is registered correctly as I'm calling other functions from it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-console-logs ?

Comment: yes, as far as I can see this only shows me things logged in javascript, I'm trying to get logs in java modules

Comment: Did you also try running `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` ?

Comment: From what I understand this is what  react-native log-android runs for us - either way, I tried it by itself and it doesn't work I think.

Comment: Indeed it looks like this is what it does https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/logAndroid/logAndroid.js#L30 .
Ah issue could be that your log is being ignored because of its tag. Could you change `Log.d("Notification","Notify App");` to `Log.d("ReactNative","Notify App");` ?

Comment: Tagging it as ReactNative works! Thanks Fidan

Comment: @FidanHakaj you are a lifesaver man! Thanks a lot, I struggled for hours

Comment: React Native 0.61, Log doesn't work for me (no matter which tag). Plain old System.out works though, so I can at least use that for really small things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you put `Log.d`s in your native code, you can access the logs with Android Device Monitor in android studio, or with this command on the terminal: 
 `adb -d logcat <your package name>:<log level> *:S`

Make sure USB debugging is enabled in your phone.

Comment: The android device monitor works, thanks! You can as well tag the logs as "ReactNative" and they show up - like Fidan Hakaj suggests in comments

Answer (score 18):

`adb logcat -s` can be used to print logs whose tags are listed in its tag list.

In the case of your question, the tag is "Notification", so you would view this with the command:

```
adb logcat -s Notification:V
```

For React Native development you will likely want the "ReactNative" and "ReactNativeJS" tags to get ReactNative and Javascript messages... so the appropriate command is:

```
adb logcat -s ReactNative:V,ReactNativeBleManager:V
```

To add the logs for any other module, look in the Java code to see what tag it is using, and add that to the list.

For example the bluetooth module "react-native-ble-manager" logs as `Log.d("ReactNativeBleManager", "The log message")`, so to include those messages change your command to:

```
adb logcat -s ReactNative:V,ReactNativeJS:V,ReactNativeBleManager:V
```

See the docs here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html for further information.

Comment: Underrated answer.  I was looking for this answer.
everyone suggesting npx react-native log-android but it logs only ReactNative and ReactNativeJS tags

Answer (score 6):

React Native CLI now ships with [a command for showing JavaScript logs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#accessing-console-logs):

```
npx react-native log-android
```

The cool thing is, if you use `Log.i("ReactNative", "My log here");` (make sure to import it at the top of your Java file with `import android.util.Log;` first), you'll see it show up in the terminal. The magic part is the "ReactNative" filter for the first part of the Log.i method call.

Comment: Must put inside something like this:

`public void changeVoiceToAlien(String file) {  Log.i("ReactNative", "My log here ALIEN"); }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-log

Example:

```
import Log from 'react-native-android-log'

// Set the default priority level (optional)
Log.setLevel(__DEV__ ? Log.VERBOSE : Log.WARN)

...
Log.v('Verbose message')    // no output in release builds
Log.w('Debugging')

// debugging message with amother tag:
Log.d('Proc2', 'warning')
```

You can see the output in the console through `adb logcat -s App:V Proc2:V` or in the OUTPUT panel of VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

And don't forget:
import android.util.Log;